# Secure Remote Password Implementation for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security, cryptography, openssl

I've been reading about Stanford's [Secure Remote Password protocol](http://srp.stanford.edu/), and it looks ideal for the sort of environment in which iPhone apps run. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a good Objective-C implementation of the protocol. Nor, as far as I can tell, do the [crypto libraries in the SDK](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/Common%20Crypto.3cc.html) implement it.

Does anyone know of such an implementation?

Failing that, what's my best bet going to be, do you think? I could try to [build OpenSSL into my app](http://www.therareair.com/2009/01/01/tutorial-how-to-compile-openssl-for-the-iphone/), but that feels like a *really big* thing to add for this one little piece. I could try to translate the [JavaScript](http://www.clipperz.com/open_source/javascript_crypto_library) or [Java](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/org/bouncycastle/crypto/agreement/srp/package-index.html) implementations into Objective-C, but that violates the #1 rule of crypto (use a known, tested implementation).

Couple of follow-up items: first, it should probably be obvious from context, but I'm going to need something that is compatible with closed-source commercial usage (the JavaScript implementation I linked to, I later noticed, is AGPL).

Also, assuming I do end up going with OpenSSL, I'm having real trouble finding an example of using it to do SRP. Their site claims the code is in there, but I can't find any evidence of it, either in the [OpenSSL documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/), or grepping the source code (v 0.9.8k). (Or am I seriously misreading things, and I still have to apply one of [their patches](http://srp.stanford.edu/download.html) to the OpenSSL source?)

**EDIT:**

What I could really use at this point is ready-to-use code, a fairly complete recipe, or some kind of example of using SRP in OpenSSL. I'm pretty sure I could cobble something together from scratch with the [protocol docs](http://srp.stanford.edu/design.html), but I'm really trying to avoid reinventing the wheel, if I can help it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OpenSSL and GnuTLS implementations of SRP-TLS are the only C-based ones I know that are maintained (TinySRP hasn't been updated since 2001, and there have been many security notices against the underlying OpenSSL version it's based on, though I don't know if they impact TinySRP itself).

That said, every iPhone project I've built has eventually had to include a copy of OpenSSL for something or other. I recommend just biting the bullet and using it. The instructions you link to work fine.

Personally, I build OpenSSL into a Universal library using lipo that has both arm and x86 versions. That way I can link to a single .a for both Simulator and Device. The lipo is very easy. Just build the two libraries and glue them together. Here's the rule from my Makefile:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo \
        -create \
        -arch armv6 iPhoneOS$(SDK_VER)/lib/$(1) \
        -arch i386 iPhoneSimulator$(SDK_VER)/lib/$(1) \
        -output iPhoneUniversal$(SDK_VER)/lib/$(1)
```

Comment: So how big does the OpenSSL library for the device end up? (And is it structured enough that the linker can leave unused bits out?)

Comment: libcrypto.a + libssl.a are over 2.5M, but they don't represent anything like that in the final binary. If I remember the last time I investigated, OpenSSL added around 400-500k to the final binary size. More than I'd want, but less than I feared. I tried to reduce the number of files in OpenSSL to improve compile time, since we only needed a few functions, but I quickly found this unworkable. OpenSSL is structured enough for the linker to split-up, but not enough for the compiler. YMMV depending on what functions you use.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of SRP in iOS platform requires OpenSSL, so a good way is to install OpenSSL via pods.

There's a good C implementation of srp by hoccer called [**csrp**](https://github.com/hoccer/csrp).

I have written an iOS wrapper for this implementation, which you can find [here](https://github.com/aceisScope/EncryptionStew). But I must mention that **csrp** is already well implemented and self-explained from its documentation.